# DOMDocument - merge elements into one XML

Tags: xml, domdocument, php-7.3

Trying to merge root and body into one XML.
The reason the 2 elements are splitted when being created is because they will be pre-constructed and exist in different files, thus loaded.

**My code:**

```
<?php


$root = new DOMDocument();
$root->loadXML('<root/>');

$body = new DOMDocument();
$body->loadXML('<body/>');

foreach ($body->documentElement->childNodes as $child) {
  $body->documentElement->appendChild(
    $body->importNode($child, TRUE)
  );
}

echo $body->saveXML();
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<body/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of `$body->documentElement->childNodes->length` is 0 as there are no childNodes for `<body/>`

As you want to import `$body` into `$root` you should append the child and import the node using root instead of child.

For example

```
$root = new DOMDocument();
$root->loadXML('<root/>');

$body = new DOMDocument();
$body->loadXML('<body/>');

foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) {
    $root->documentElement->appendChild(
        $root->importNode($child, TRUE)
    );
}

echo $root->saveXML();
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><body/></root>
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/sSDRI)